# How to disable read operation from Combobox in WinForms?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, combobox

I know the command in WPF but what is its equivalent in WinForms?

```
cboclient.IsHitTestVisible = false;
cboclient.Focusable = false;
```

Using this command the combo-box is not disabled but the user can't open it for reading the data. How I can accomplish this in WinForms? thanks

Details: I have 3 combobox on my form when the form initially loads only the third combobox can not be opened for reading data. When the user selects a value in the first two combobox then based on those two values the third combobox is enabled to display data from DB.

Note: Here I don't want to disable the third combobox. Because it will give the user the a false expression.

Comment: Have you tried `cboclient.Enabled = false;`?

Comment: yes....It disables Combobox

Comment: And that's not what you want? Please describe what you're after...

Comment: I simply want if no record is present in db . then state of combobox is user cant open it for reading ..It remain alive and enabled

Comment: Are you looking for a combobox with no items?

Comment: So adding an `if` statement around the `.Enabled = false;` line above doesn't work?  You're starting to get into specifics about your application that you haven't exposed which are practically impossible for us to guess...

Comment: now see details in edited question ..

Comment: The answer is the same regardless... add logic to make your application behave the way you expect. Otherwise it won't.

Answer (score 1):

You can catch the message `WM_MOUSEACTIVATE` and discard it to prevent user from focusing the combobox by mouse and also prevent hittesting. Catch the message `WM_SETFOCUS` to prevent user from focusing the combobox by keyboard. Try this code:

```
public class ComboBoxEx : ComboBox
{    
    public ComboBoxEx(){
        IsHitTestVisible = true;
    }
    public bool IsHitTestVisible { get; set; }
    public bool ReadOnly { get; set; }
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {            
        if (!IsHitTestVisible)
        {
            if (m.Msg == 0x21)//WM_MOUSEACTIVATE = 0x21
            {
                m.Result = (IntPtr)4;//no activation and discard mouse message
                return;
            }
            //WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x200, WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x202
            if (m.Msg == 0x200 || m.Msg == 0x202) return;
        }
        //WM_SETFOCUS = 0x7
        if (ReadOnly && m.Msg == 0x7) return;
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
    //Discard key messages
    public override bool PreProcessMessage(ref Message msg)
    {
        if (ReadOnly) return true;
        return base.PreProcessMessage(ref msg);
    }
}
//Usage
comboBoxEx1.ReadOnly = true;
comboBoxEx1.IsHitTestVisible = false;
```

Comment: Excellent answer. It shows how something that is achieved by setting 2 properties in WPF requires a bunch of horrible hacks full of magic numbers and bizarre stuff all over the place in winforms.

Comment: @HighCore yes, I think this is relevant enough to be put into your collection, however this is not kind of the bottom of winforms, there are many much more complicated codes out there, all those complicated codes can be made much simpler with WPF, that's not strange because WPF is a much higher-level library, the next UI technology of course :|

Comment: what's really disgusting about it is all those `0x200`, `0x202`... what the heck is that? Why don't they create a freakin `enum` or something? Looks like going back to the VB6 days interacting with the Windows 95 API

Comment: @HighCore in fact there is a class (not offcial/standard) containing all win32 stuff including such constants (defined as enum or named constant), I just posted the constants in this answer, in production code, we had better use that class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code:

```
cboclient.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
cboclient.DropDownHeight = 1;
cboclient.DropDownWidth = 1;
cboclient.TabStop = false;
```

for displaying combobox as a readonly one you can use:

```
cboclient.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup;
```

or

```
cboclient.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  **if** statement on OnSelectionChangedSelectionChanged event.

```
  private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      //here your if statement
    }
```